# Getting different variables using .each while using one simple script

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, youtube

I am trying to get a link from some youtube embedded video's, in order to make some links to them, which in their place trigger a nice fancybox to watch the video in.

Getting the ID from the embedded video, and replacing it in the right link isnt the problem. It gets dirty as soon as I try to code in the loop.

The javascript I use is as following:

```
$('.portfolio_det iframe').each(function(i) {
    var videolink = this.src.replace('http://www.youtube.com/embed/', '');
    var videolink = videolink.replace('?fs=1&feature=oembed', '')

    $('.portfolio_thumb .youtubeLink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('href', "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videolink);
    });
});
```

The Last piece of the code retrieves the link in 
Though they all get the href created on the first youtube video.

How do I set the variable to be in the loop aswell?

To make it all a bit clearer, here is a jsfiddle from the setup:

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTWS8/)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining var videolink twice and leaving the ; off of the end of the second one.
The second line should be:

```
videolink = videolink.replace('?fs=1&feature=oembed', '');
```

Comment: I always thought re-using the same var name, in order to get a new value for the same var.
Anyhow, it doesnt change anything if I rename the second var to anything else..

Comment: you can reuse the same var name all you want, just don't try defining it with the var prefix more than once.  IE7 will get very angry.

Comment: IE7 will get me angry anyway :P So I most of the time ignore the failured of it. However, thnx for the tip about the IE7 angryness

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable outside the loop. Also once if you have defined a variable you dont have to put `var` in front of it.

```
var videolink;
$('.portfolio_det iframe').each(function(i) {
    videolink = this.src.replace('http://www.youtube.com/embed/', '');
    videolink = videolink.replace('?fs=1&feature=oembed', '')

    $('.portfolio_thumb .youtubeLink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('href', "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videolink);
    });
});
```